# How can I add xml file to the classpath in intelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

I have a xml file in com.jason.jdbc.config package, and I have mark java as Sources, but the xml file cann’t be add to the classpath, why? What’s wrong with me?
[my code directory before compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f2Qu.png)

[my code directory aftercompile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC7Vu.png)

my Idea Version is 2016.2.1. i have google many times, and also e try mark config directory  as 'resource'.but if config marked as resource, Idea will complie and copy databaseConfig.xml to classpath root. does anyone have any good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use Maven. In a Maven project, resources go to `src/main/resources`. `src/main/java` is for Java source files only.

Comment: first  thx ~, yes, as u see, i use maven, but i don't want to use `maven` to compile my project, just want to use idea's  `run` button to compile my project.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. As long as IDEA imports the project from the maven pom, it expects the project to be a Maven project and use Maven's rules.

Comment: soga! i have done success, u really help me a lot, this problem has token me all day